# Quality problems when converting tiff to JPG in flutter

Tags: flutter, image, dart

I have a tiff image file. This is stored in `cache memory` using the `path_provider` package.

```
final cacheDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
File _tiffFile = File('$cacheDir/img1.tiff'); // /data/user/0/package_name/cache/img1.tiff
```

Now convert it to a 'jpg' file.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:image/image.dart' as imageLib;

imageLib.Image? _image = imageLib.decodeImage(_file.readAsBytesSync());
imageLib.Image _tempImg = imageLib.copyResize(_image!, width: (size.width * 0.9).toInt(), height: (size.height * 0.7).toInt());
File _pngImg = File('$cacheDir/img1.jpg')..writeAsBytesSync(imageLib.encodeJpg(_tempImg, quality: 100));
```

It is set to 100 even if you don't enter the `quality` of the `encodeJpg` method. But the quality of my 'jpg' image is very poor. Is there a way to convert it to high definition?

Comment: How is the image quality if you don't perform the resizing step?  It's not clear what resizing algorithm is used; nearest-neighbor is likely to generate ugly artifacts. Incidentally, using a variable named `_pngImg` for a JPEG file is very misleading.

Comment: Indeed, [`copyResize`](https://pub.dev/documentation/image/latest/image/copyResize.html) by default uses nearest-neighbor.  Try using `Interpolation.cubic`.